# Drupal chat slowdown my application

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, module, chat

I am using [Drupalchat](http://drupal.org/project/Drupalchat) for my application. The issue is that my application getting very much slow down after put this chat system. I think the problem will be due to Ajax, it's keep on polling to the server for frequently to check the chat messages(incoming or outgoing). How to fix this issue to fasten my application ?

Also I am curious about how the facebook and gmail chat systems are working in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, AJAX chat of any sort is notorious for slowing servers for just this reason. Probably the most efficient alternative is to use Node.js, which keeps a connection open and only communicates when the server has something to push to the browser.

This is new technology, but an early alpha version of a Drupal chatroom module implementation which uses Node.js has been released, with details [here](http://groups.drupal.org/node-js).

Comment: Any other solution instead of Node.js?

Comment: There are other modules, but they will all work in the same way by polling the server. Node.js is the only one that won't. You could always get a more powerful server, of course.